# Insane world of 'detector' switches

Tags: switches

I hope someone here can help me understand a dilemma that I'm facing.  I have a design that incorporates two limit switches to limit the ends of travel of a slider plate.  My circuit uses the switches in series, either of which will break a conductivity path, such that the path 'defaults' to a resistor pulling the path to ground if either limit is reached.  So, I'm looking for an angled 'detector' (see attached) switch that is NC when not actuated and NO when actuated.  However, among the HUNDREDS of NO 'detector' switches at Digi-Key for example (many of which are available singly) when not actuated, not a single ONE can be found with a NC circuit in less quantity than several hundred.  Can anyone help me understand why the world of electronics manufacturing/distributing has arranged itself into that triple witching?

Does it just make more sense to pass a signal/voltage when activated rather than break a circuit when activated for implementing a 'detector' function?  Safety or reliability issues?  My design seems efficient and does the job with the fewest possible parts and potentially the least cost.  Why does the switch manufacturing/distribution world seem so insane?

[image]

Comment: Many of these switches are used for safety interlocks and rely on being closed when safe, so when panels are attached they close the switch for (by convention) safe mode to provide a small current for a monitoring circuit. The internal construction is also sometimes simpler for this mode of operation.

Comment: Many limit switches are double-throw, so you can use them as either Normally Open or Normally Closed. Digikey has thousands of SPDT limit switches in stock, and most can be purchased singly.

Comment: Hmm.  Only seeing the current says 'all ok'.  Everything has to be working properly to get the ok signal.  Not seeing the current could be due to more factors than just the panel not being attached, which is potentially more problematic or even a safety issue.  Guess it makes sense.  But not even ONE?!

Comment: Peter, not of the 'detector' variety.  There's probably an appropriate switch to be found, but it's proving very hard to find it.  I have low actuation force, broad face being transverse to the direction of actuation for good adhesion, low price and low quantity to consider too.  Engineering can be such a fricking pain!  I should have pursued an art history degree.

Comment: @user1621287 Can you show us a picture of the situation you are working with? I see words here that have a very wide range of interpretation and, at least to me, it would help a great deal to see exactly what's being addressed, the speeds involved, distances of travel allowed from "no problem" to "stop NOW!", etc. All this helps a great deal. Many of us have used a variety of switches in solving similar problems. But unable to see what you see, it's hard to know what part of our experiences (well, mine anyway) to draw from.

Comment: I appreciate your attention, Jonk.  I think I found a couple of candidates that will do at Digi-Key:  EG4934-ND, ‎CKN10387-ND‎

Comment: I tried to respond more fully, but SE limits the number of characters in a reply, doesn't make dropping a photo into a reply easy, and times out an edit unexpectedly, so I said frack it.  Thanks all.